# Proof by Cases: $\operatorname{max}\{x,y\} + \operatorname{min}\{x,y\}=x+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

So I'm told to "[u]se proof by cases to prove that $\operatorname{max}\{x,y\} + \operatorname{min}\{x,y\}=x+y$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$." What does this mean?

Answer (score 8):

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have one of the following to be true:
\begin{align}x & < y\\ x & =y\\ x & >y \end{align}
Now consider each case and conclude what you want.

For instance, consider the case $x<y$. We then have $\max\{x,y\} = y$ and $\min\{x,y\}=x$. This gives us $$\max \{x,y\} + \min \{x,y\} = y + x  = x +y$$ Similarly, argue out the remaining two cases as well.

Comment: So how am I to learn something from this? I mean, what is it that is trying to be carried across here?

Comment: @Trancot Consider each of the above cases. For instance, consider the case $x<y$. We then have $\max\{x,y\} = y$ and $\min\{x,y\}=x$. This hence gives us $$\max \{x,y\} + \min \{x,y\} = y + x  = x +y$$ Similarly, argue out the remaining two cases as well.

Comment: My professor speaks of things like $\underset{i=0}{\overset{n}{\huge\wedge}}~~p_i \implies q$, so is this proof-by-case business, the same thing?

Comment: @Trancot: I guess what you should learn from that is that sometimes the best way to prove a general relation is to divide the problem into a complete set of special cases which are easier to treat individually.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are three natural cases: $x\lt y$, $x=y$, and $x\gt y$.

But breaking up into cases is not **really** necessary. Because of the symmetry, we could say something like "Without loss of generality we may assume that $x\le y$."

If, for example, you examine the case $x\lt y$, and compute $\max(x,y)$ and $\min(x,y)$, you will quickly be able to verify that the equation holds in that case. Same with the others.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\min\{x,y\}=x$ when $x\le y$, but $\min\{x,y\}=y$ when $x>y$. Similarly, when $x\le y$ we have $\max\{x,y\}=y$, but when $x>y$ we have $\max\{x,y\}=x$. The suggestion is that you break the problem into these two cases: treat $x\le y$ as one case and $x>y$ as the other.

> **Case 1:** If $x\le y$, then $\min\{x,y\}=x$ and $\max\{x,y\}=y$, so ... .

And similarly for the other case.

This isn’t the only possible division into cases, by the way: you could also use $x<y$ and $x\ge y$, or the three-way division into $x<y$, $x=y$, and $x>y$.

The point is that $\max\{x,y\}$ and $\min\{x,y\}$ depend on the relationship between $x$ and $y$. If you split the proof up according to the possibilities for that relationship, you can arrange to make the argument uniform **within** each case, even though the argument in one case may have to be a bit different from the argument in another.